# Perl's YAML::XS and unicode

Tags: perl, unicode, yaml

I am trying to use perl's `YAML::XS` module on unicode letters and it doesn't seem working the way it should.

I write this in the script (which is saved in utf-8)

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; 
my $hash = {č => "ř"}; #czech letters with unicode codes U+010D and U+0159

use YAML::XS;
my $s = YAML::XS::Dump($hash);
print $s;
```

Instead of something sane, `-: Å` is printed. According to [this link](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-LibYAML/lib/YAML/XS.pm#USING_YAML%3a%3aXS_WITH_UNICODE), though, it should be working fine.

Yes, when I `YAML::XS::Load` it back, I got the correct strings again, but I don't like the fact the dumped string seems to be in some wrong encoding.

Am I doing something wrong? I am always unsure about unicode in perl, to be frank...

clarification: my console supports UTF-8. Also, when I print it to file, opened with utf8 handle with `open $file, ">:utf8"` instead of `STDOUT`, it still doesn't print correct utf-8 letters.

Comment: Printed to what? Does your console support UTF-8?

Comment: @socket puppet: Yes, it does. Also, it stays the same if I print it to file (with utf8 handle) instead of STDOUT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're doing something wrong.  You've misunderstood what [the link you mentioned](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::XS#USING_YAML::XS_WITH_UNICODE) means.  `Dump` & `Load` work with raw UTF-8 bytes; i.e. strings containing UTF-8 but *with the UTF-8 flag off*.

When you print those bytes to a filehandle with the `:utf8` layer, they get interpreted as Latin-1 and converted to UTF-8, producing double-encoded output (which can be read back successfully as long as you double-decode it).  You want to `binmode STDOUT, ':raw'` instead.

Another option is to call [utf8::decode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8) on the string returned by `Dump`.  This will convert the raw UTF-8 bytes to a character string (with the UTF-8 flag on).  You can then print the string to a `:utf8` filehandle.

So, either

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":raw"; 
my $hash = {č => "ř"}; #czech letters with unicode codes U+010D and U+0159

use YAML::XS;
my $s = YAML::XS::Dump($hash);
print $s;
```

Or

```
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; 
my $hash = {č => "ř"}; #czech letters with unicode codes U+010D and U+0159

use YAML::XS;
my $s = YAML::XS::Dump($hash);
utf8::decode($s);
print $s;
```

Likewise, when reading from a file, you want to read in `:raw` mode or use `utf8::encode` on the string before passing it to `Load`.

When possible, you should just use `DumpFile` & `LoadFile`, letting YAML::XS deal with opening the file correctly.  But if you want to use STDIN/STDOUT, you'll have to deal with `Dump` & `Load`.

Comment: you probably want to read the file with `LoadFile`. so YAML::XS takes care of the gory details

Comment: @mirod, if you can.  But I don't think `DumpFile` works with STDOUT.

Comment: sure, but how often in real life (not during development, in the final code) do you output YAML to STDOUT? Usually I store it in a file, to be used later.

Comment: Aha! Yes, I did indeed misunderstood what "utf8 octets" mean in the context of the documentation. This makes sense. (And I did dump the hash to string and then manually saving that to file to be "more sure" the file is saved right. Seems like a bad idea after all :))

Comment: It's also important to understand that ":utf8" might not be what you actually want as that is the relaxed UTF-8 handler. See https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8 for details.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you don't use `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";`. Just don't ask me why.

Comment: That is.... weird. I am cautiously giving you +1, but I am waiting for an answer that will explain what is going on.

Comment: after reading again the docs of the module, it looks like it treats all strings as utf8 (in USING YAML::XS WITH UNICODE: "YAML::XS only deals with streams of utf8 octets."). So all strings are utf8, but they do not have the utf8 flag on (you can check this with Encode::is_utf8), probably because YAML::XS is an interface to libyaml, which is not Perl. Bottom line, if you want to save your YAML to a file, you should probably use DumpFile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the next for the utf-8 JSON and YAML. No error handling, but can show how to do.
The bellow allows me:

- uses NFC normalisation on input and NO NDF on output. Simply useing everything in NFC
- can edit the YAML/JSON files with utf8 enabled vim and bash tools
- "inside" the perl works things like `\w` regexes and `lc` `uc` and so on (at least for my needs)
- source code is utf8, so can write regexes `/á/`

My "broilerplate"...

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use feature qw(unicode_strings);
use charnames qw(:full);
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Encode qw(encode decode);
use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFD NFC);

use File::Slurp;
use YAML::XS;
use JSON::XS;

run();
exit;

sub run {
    my $yfilein = "./in.yaml"; #input yaml
    my $jfilein = "./in.json"; #input json
    my $yfileout = "./out.yaml"; #output yaml
    my $jfileout = "./out.json"; #output json

    my $ydata = load_utf8_yaml($yfilein);
    my $jdata = load_utf8_json($jfilein);

    #the "uc" is not "fully correct" but works for my needs
    $ydata->{$_} = uc($ydata->{$_}) for keys %$ydata;
    $jdata->{$_} = uc($jdata->{$_}) for keys %$jdata;

    save_utf8_yaml($yfileout, $ydata);
    save_utf8_json($jfileout, $jdata);
}


#using File::Slurp for read/write files
#NFC only on input - and not NFD on output (change this if you want)
#this ensure me than i can edit and copy/paste filenames without problems

sub load_utf8_yaml { return YAML::XS::Load(encode_nfc_read(shift)) }
sub load_utf8_json { return decode_json(encode_nfc_read(shift)) }
sub encode_nfc_read { return encode 'utf8', NFC read_file shift, { binmode => ':utf8' } }
#more effecient
sub rawsave_utf8_yaml { return write_file shift, {binmode=>':raw'}, YAML::XS::Dump shift }
#similar as for json
sub save_utf8_yaml { return write_file shift, {binmode=>':utf8'}, decode 'utf8', YAML::XS::Dump shift }
sub save_utf8_json { return write_file shift, {binmode=>':utf8'}, JSON::XS->new->pretty(1)->encode(shift) }
```

You can try the next `in.yaml`

```
---
á: ä
č: ď
é: ě
í: ĺ
ľ: ň
ó: ô
ö: ő
ŕ: ř
š: ť
ú: ů
ü: ű
ý: ž
```